# L'Hospital and rate of change of definite integrals

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to evaluate a rational function that involves the following limit in the denominator and the same limit and integral albeit with different limits of integration in the numerator.

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\theta=\frac{-\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^n\theta\, d\theta$

This was part of a challenge problem in what is more or less a Calculus 2 class, so that is my level of understanding (mis or otherwise :) ).

I can compute the limits and I end up with a $\frac{0}{0}$ indeterminate form. My thought was to use L'Hospital's Rule to resolve the limit, but the problem is the definite integral--the derivative of which would be zero. My approach was to use a restatement of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, which tells us:

$\displaystyle\frac{d}{dx}\int_{t=a}^x f(t)\,dt=f(x)$, where $a$ is a constant.

Using a variation of that fact, I wrote:

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{d}{dn}2\int_{\theta=\frac{1}{n}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^{n}\theta\, d\theta=\lim_{n\to\infty}2\left[\frac{d}{dn}\int\cos^{n}\theta\, d\theta\vert_{\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}}-\cos^{n}\frac{1}{n}\right]=\lim_{n\to\infty}2\left(0-\cos^{n}\frac{1}{n}\right)$

At that point I used MacLaurin/Binomial Series to approximate $\cos^{n}\frac{1}{n}$ so I could take the limit.

My question is whether substituting $\frac{1}{n}$ into the lower limit of integration is a correct/reasonable approach? Are there better approaches? It seemed fairly natural to do the substitution since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$ and it converts the function of $\theta$ to a function of $n$ which allows us to compute the derivative with respect to $n$. I ended up with the right answer, but I've encountered some skepticism as to whether my approach is valid.

Thanks in advance for all thoughts.

Comment: $n$ is an integer. So it can not play the same role as $x$ (in particular, no derivative with respect to $n$).

Comment: Note that $\cos$ is bounded between $0$ and $1$ on $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$, and that, for any $\alpha \neq 0$, $\cos^n \alpha \rightarrow 0$ when $n$ goes to $+\infty$.

Comment: Regarding your first comment, that's what I was afraid somebody would say :). I was thinking that since all I cared about was the behavior in the limit, it wouldn't matter that $n$ went from being fixed to variable. But I guess the problem is that I created an entirely new function by doing this...Assuming different definite integrals and the need to apply L'Hospital's Rule and take derviatives,  is the idea of substituting to create a variable limit of integration the right approach provided it doesn't change the behavior of the function?

Comment: @user7440, regarding your second comment, so that would imply that $\displaystyle\int_{\theta=\frac{-\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^{n}\theta d\theta=1d\theta$? I guess that since the numerator is the same integral--albeit with different limits of integration--I'd get the same answer and I could rightfully claim that $d\theta$ was the same in both cases. So could claim that $\frac{1d\theta}{1d\theta}=1$?

Comment: Thank you @user7440 for your comments!

Comment: $\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos^n \theta d \theta = \int_{0}^{\alpha} \cos^n \theta d \theta + \int_{\alpha}^{\pi/2} \cos^n \theta d \theta$  ... Select $\alpha$ such that $\pi/2| \cos \alpha |^{n}$ goes to $0$ at the speed you want. And then $\alpha \rightarrow 0$ so that the first integral goes to $0$.